# Standard vs Expert Sphere Grid

Tags: final-fantasy-10

The International version of Final Fantasy X gives the option at new game to choose between Standard and Expert Sphere Grids. (This also applies to the HD remaster versions.)

It appears that the Standard Sphere Grid is larger though. Does that mean that the theoretical maximum stats of characters on the Standard Sphere Grid would be greater than the theoretical maximum stats of characters on the Expert Sphere Grid?

If that is the case, then what would be the reason for playing using the Expert Sphere Grid?

Comment: I was sure this was already asked, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: The first part was asked [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190708/does-stat-growth-mean-less-max-stats).

Comment: @AdamV Thanks for the link! I read in your link from the previous answer: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Sphere_Grid#Expert_Mode That: "The Expert grid has fewer nodes in total than the Standard grid (68 less), but it still contains enough nodes to maximize the characters' statistics, to exception in three stats at maximum, unlike the Standard grid which are two." I'm not sure if I understand what that's saying? Does that mean that you can only max out 3 stats on the standard, and 2 stats on the expert?

Comment: I think it means this: it looks like there are 10 total stats in FFX. If you use the Standard Grid, there are enough empty spaces for you to max out 8 different stats (all but two), but in the Expert Grid, you can only max out 7 (all but three).

Comment: (I agree it's not worded very well.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean that the theoretical maximum stats of characters on the Standard Sphere Grid would be greater than the theoretical maximum stats of characters on the Expert Sphere Grid?

Yes, by ~70 spheres, if I recall correctly.

> If that is the case, then what would be the reason for playing using the Expert Sphere Grid?

In the Expert Sphere Grid, all your characters start out very near the center, allowing you to choose different paths fairly early on, rather than having set pathways that you'd need high-level Key Spheres to break out of.

Comment: Sounds like there's nothing to be gained from Expert Mode if I'm planning on stat maxing anyway.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Expert Mode was to avoid the problem of having every character losing their individuality near end-game (such as happens with FF12.) Maybe I was wrong?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Seems like there would be more loss of individuality not less, as all the characters start out in the center of the Sphere Grid, so there's the potential that you end up with 7 Aurons if you choose to take all characters in the same direction. (Not that that wouldn't be fun.)